# Typescript inferred type Error

Tags: typescript

am in learning process of TypeScript. The below code is throwing errors :

> Error:- Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
>
> [ts] Declaration or statement expected.

```
class duckType{
public validType(){}
  var myVar:any = {id:1, name:"ABC"};

    myVar = {id:2};
}
}
var myType = new duckType();
myType.validType();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the trailing brace `}`:

```
public validType() {
```